# Acitivity Lifecycle (moving back and forth between Activities)

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

As Android newbie I started to wonder about the Activity lifecycle. I'm having an Activity that loads a list of Persons and displays them. Upon the click of a Person I want to open another Activity showing the details of that Person. I'm currently doing this by creating an Intent on the "PersonDetailActivity" which I then start. So far so good. On the PersonDetail page I would like to have a menu action to go back to the Person list. I again applied the same technique, meaning an Intent that brings me back to the PersonListActivity.

Now I started to wonder what returning to the PersonListActivity means. Will a new instance get created and will I have to reload the persons that it displays in the list? Can you come back to the same instance, avoiding having to reload the list again? Do you then have to pass a pointer to yourself via the intent to the other Activity?

So when will and Activity be re-instantiated and when will it not. Any hints or suggestions are more than welcome. Maybe there are some patterns to be applied for these back and forth menu actions that I'm not yet aware of.

Thanks,

Vincent

Answer (score 1):

Yes,,. Call `finish()` in second Activity instead of starting new Activity..

There is basically something called Activity stack which stores all Activities in the order they were started.. so if start new Actvity , that sits on top of the stack and preveous one gets below it.. when you call finish the Activity is poped out..

if you don't want to call `finish()` correct waht ever you were doing then add flag `ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` in manifest for the 1st Activity..

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you just call the `finish()` method on your `PersonDetailActivity`

`PersonDetailActivity.this.finish();`

it will activate the `onResume()` method from the Activity that is on the top of the finished one, which here would be your PersonsActivity. You can specify in your `onResume()` method what you want to perform when turning back there.

Comment: This comments really helped me. Thanks, will be trying it out as we speak.